# soldering 3M MDR (Mini Delta Ribbon) connectors?

Tags: soldering, breakout, interconnect

3M MDR connectors ([see here for details](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Interconnect/Home/Products/ProductCatalog/)) seem to be a pretty common interconnect system. Has anyone tried making a few cables and boxes with these without buying the 3M tooling kit? Since the kit is $2000 ([from e.g. Digikey](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=3M3829-ND)) it would be nice not to have to buy this if I'm only hooking up a few things.

Specifically, I'm looking at their [50-pin connector](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?vendor=0&keywords=10150-3000PE) with [this](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=MB50S-100-ND) cable. Is it feasible to connect these with nothing more than a decent soldering iron?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions! I've upvoted all answers instead of arbitrarily selecting one as "the" answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't waste your time trying to solder them, it won't work. Most distributors will make up cables for you, it shouldn't be expensive. Or. choose a connector system that is easier and cheaper to assemble.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately I'm stuck with existing equipment that uses the MDR system, and I need to (1) break out a few of the channels, and (2) interface it with a [MillMax .050"][1] connector on the other end. I don't know of a distributor that can accomodate that... [1][http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=9002055]

Comment: I'd design a little PCB for that sort of thing.

Comment: i'll second making a breakout board...

Comment: Yeah, but the linked connector is a *solder cup* connector. It may not be possible to terminate it to a PCB.

Comment: There are also PCB mount versions of the connector. That would be the neat way of doing it; sounds like something I need to learn how to do. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Many solder cup connectors are spaced so that you can actually slide a double-sided circuit board between the rows. With the right trace patterns you should just be able to solder it up and go. Almost every USB serial port dongle I have ever seen uses this kind of construction, and long ago when dinosaurs roamed the earth we soldered PCMCIA connectors to boards using the same method. It beats the crap out of trying to hand-crimp or solder each connection individually!

Answer (score 2):

The connector you linked to is specced as a Solder Cup connector, so it *Should* be possible to hand solder.

It may be a bit fiddly though.

Answer (score 1):

This looks perfectly solder-able to me. My record is soldering 80-pin cable, so your 50-pin one will eat less of your Patience. Also, you should think about finish insulation & look&feel :-)

Maybe heat shrink tube on each wire/connection...